# C++ ATL | _InternalQueryInterface identifier not found

Tags: c++, winapi, com, atl

I have the following class

```
class SearchCompleteFunction : public ISearchCompletedCallback
    {

    public:

        SearchCompleteFunction()
        { }
        ~SearchCompleteFunction()
        { }

        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Invoke( ISearchJob *searchJob, ISearchCompletedCallbackArgs *callbackArgs )
        {
            std::cout << "Invoked" << std::endl;
            return S_OK;
        }
    };

// Now I am trying to BeginSearch
    {
        CComObject<SearchCompleteFunction>* searchCompleteFunc = nullptr;
        HRESULT hres = CComObject<SearchCompleteFunction>::CreateInstance( &searchCompleteFunc );
        CComPtr<ISearchJob> searchJob = nullptr;

        hr = ptrUpdateSearcher->BeginSearch(_bstr_t(bstrCriteria.c_str()), searchCompleteFunc, CComVariant(L"Scanning"), &searchJob);
    }
```

When I compile this piece of code, I get
'_InternalQueryInterface': identifier not found.

I used also

```
BEGIN_COM_MAP( SearchCompleteFunction )
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY( ISearchCompletedCallback )
END_COM_MAP()
```

but then I got more than 10 errors.

Please help me to successfully compile and test this.
I appreciate your help!

Comment: 1) You forgot to ask a question. 2) There is no __InternalQueryInterface_ in your Code snippet.

Comment: @nada 1) Done, sorry, I taught it was obvious. 2) there isn't any _InternalQueryInterface in my code, when I double click on the error it takes me to atlcom.h header

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to include a header, but I can't know for sure since your example is not verifiable on its own.

Comment: It is a pretty basic issue, you'll get this compile error when the BEGIN_COM_MAP declaration is missing.  You can't do without it, even if it generates only a single compile error.  That it now generates more errors with the map added is not unusual at all, the compiler now gets to verify that you implemented the interface correctly.  Hard to help you when you don't tell us what you see.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inherit from `CComObjectRootEx` as well. Basically you need to follow ATL tutorial to get started with ATL COM objects.

- [direct example here on page 251](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=S6QrxiaonBIC&pg=PA251&lpg=PA251&dq=CComObjectRootEx+BEGIN_COM_MAP&source=bl&ots=mU_3hNzHmV&sig=ACfU3U0cagVd2Yd5tY2B4XHyhP6sB-5Wrw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_1JDf-_jkAhWk1aYKHYJrBlgQ6AEwA3oECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=CComObjectRootEx%20BEGIN_COM_MAP&f=false)
- [Fundamentals of ATL COM Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/fundamentals-of-atl-com-objects?view=vs-2019)
- [Various stuff on github](https://github.com/pfeilbr/repo/blob/39a633666ca2ba356a5c065744f0cab0183b86a7/C/VC/projects/test/Foo.h):

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CFoo : 
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CFoo, &CLSID_Foo>,
    public IDispatchImpl<IFoo, &IID_IFoo, &LIBID_TESTLib>
{
public:
    CFoo()
    {
    }

DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_FOO)

DECLARE_PROTECT_FINAL_CONSTRUCT()

BEGIN_COM_MAP(CFoo)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IFoo)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
END_COM_MAP()

// IFoo
...
```